# Replace prototype dynamically by changing constructor property

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make some good code example to experience JavaScript's "classlessness". This is what I have come up with so far:

```
function One() {}
function Two() {}

One.prototype.a = 5;
Two.prototype.b = 4;

var obj = new One();
print("1) ctor =", obj.constructor, "a =", obj.a, " b =", obj.b);
obj.constructor = Two;
print("1) ctor =", obj.constructor, "a =", obj.a, " b =", obj.b);

var objTwo = new obj.constructor();
print("2) ctor =", objTwo.constructor, "a =", objTwo.a, " b =", objTwo.b);
```

And these are corresponding prints:

```
1) ctor = function One() {
} a = 5  b = undefined
1) ctor = function Two() {
} a = 5  b = undefined
2) ctor = function Two() {
} a = undefined  b = 4
```

My question is why prototype chain does not work here by the book? I run my example in ideone with JavaScript (spidermonkey) (spidermonkey-1.7). It looks like in real life prototype is accessed somehow else than `constructor.prototype`?

P.S. Further experimentation shows that assigning to `obj.constructor` adds new property, which shadows the original one. Why?..

Comment: The `constructor` property of each instance does not serve any purpose internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, your `var obj` doesn't have a property named `constructor`. When you print it, it's resolved via its prototype (`One.prototype`) -- all prototypes have a constructor. When you assign `obj.constructor = Two` you create an own property in `obj` which shadows the prototype property. This new prop means nothing to the engine and doesn't affect inheritance in any way.

In general, "constructor" appears to be a pure informative property and doesn't serve any particular purpose. It's just a backlink from a function's prototype back to the parent function. See [Creating functions](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2) and [Construct](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks, very logical explanation. `console.log(One.prototype.hasOwnProperty("constructor"));` prints `true`

Answer (score 1):

yes, There is `Object.__proto__` and the direct `Object.prototype`. If you print One.prototype you should see the desired results. If you do `console.dir(someInstance);` you will get instance variables listed directly underneath `someInstance`.

After that you can expand the `prototype` and you will see the methods you have defined for that prototype.(eg. `One.prototype.doSomething = function(a){}`);

Read more about `Object.__proto__`it [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) and more about `Object.prototype`(the standard) [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you went into the mechanics and then started pulling wires. There is nothing by the book really going on here because you disrupted the natural sequence by injecting this pointer

```
obj.constructor = Two;
```

That is not the proper way to do inheritance. This is:

```
function One() {}
function Two() {}

One.prototype.a = 5;
Two.prototype = new One();
Two.prototype.b = 4;
```

Now any object instantiated with `new Two()` will show the `is-a` relationship (inheritance) properly in the constructor. Here is a **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VEdYA/)** showing the difference.

Comment: Well, I merely assumed prototype is resolved via constructor property. As alex23 describes, my assumption was wrong. That is all I wanted to clarify. Thanks for your time writing your answer.